# php if form field is empty set a variable

Tags: php, jobamatic

Currently My API is giving out the following http request:

http://api.simplyhired.com/a/jobs-api/xml-v2/q-Golf%golf/k-golf?pshid=mypshid&ssty=2&cflg=r&auth=myauth&clip=76.68.98.34

I need it to format like the below after changes to the API:

http://api.simplyhired.com/a/jobs-api/xml-v2/q-golf/sb-rd/ws-10/pn-1?pshid=mypshid&ssty=2&cflg=r&auth=myauth&clip=76.68.98.34

q =  the search term and what I need it to do is default to "golf" if the search keyword section is blank (or for first time visitor)

So I need to code something like the below:

if $query is null then $query = 'golf'
else $query = trim($query);

I don't understand the following line and believe that this is what needs to be adjusted. This is set while in the plugin settings section for a default searchterm. I would just like to change in the code itself.

```
if( strpos( $query, 'golf' ) === false) { 
        $query .= 'golf';
    }
```

Here is the php code from the WP plugin that I am working with:

```
    <?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/RemoteConnector.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/JobamaticXMLParser.php');

define('JOBAMATIC_INVALID_URL_ERROR', 3000);
define('JOBAMATIC_XMLPARSER_ERROR', 3001);

class SimplyHiredJobamaticAPI {
  protected $pshid;
  protected $jbd;
  protected $ssty;
  protected $cflg;
  protected $auth;
  protected $clip;
  protected $error;
  protected $code;
  protected $data;

  const JOBAMATIC_ENDPOINT = 'http://api.simplyhired.com/a/jobs-api/xml-v2/';


  public function __construct($pshid, $jbd) {
    $this->pshid = trim($pshid);
    $this->jbd = trim($jbd);
    $this->ssty = 2;
    $this->cflg = 'r';
    $this->auth = 'myauth';
    $this->clip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $this->error = NULL;
    $this->code = NULL;
    $this->data = NULL;
  }

  public function search($query, $size = 10, $page = 0, $location = '', $miles = 5, *emphasized text*$sort = 'rd', $constant = 'golf') {


    if( strpos( $query, 'golf' ) === false) {
        $query .= 'golf';
    }
    $params = array(
      'q' => rawurlencode(trim($query)),
      'sb' => $sort,
      'ws' => $size,
      'pn' => (intval($page) < 1 ? 0 : intval($page)),
    'k'  => $constant,
    );

    if (!is_null($location) && $location != '') {
      $params['l'] = rawurlencode($location);
    }

    if (!is_null($location) && intval($miles) > 0) {
      $params['m'] = $miles;
    }

    $this->call($params);
    if($this->code == 200) {
      return $this->data;
    } else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }

  protected function call($criteria) {
    $url = self::JOBAMATIC_ENDPOINT . '%s?';

    $api_identity = array(
      'pshid' => $this->pshid,
      /*'jbd' => $this->jbd,*/
      'ssty' => $this->ssty,
      'cflg' => $this->cflg,
      'auth' => $this->auth,
      'clip' => $this->clip,

    );

    $identity_string = array();
    foreach ($api_identity as $key => $value) {
      $identity_string[] = $key . '=' . $value;
    }

    $url .= implode('&', $identity_string);

    $params = array();

    foreach ($criteria as $key => $value) {
      $params[] = $key . '-' . $value;
    }

    $url = sprintf($url, implode('/', $params));
    echo $url;
    try {
      $connector = new RemoteConnector($url);
      $this->code = $connector->getStatus();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      $this->error = $e->getMessage();
      $this->code = JOBAMATIC_INVALID_URL_ERROR;
      return;
    }

    $this->parseXML($connector->__toString());
  }

  protected function parseXML($data) {
    $parser = JobamaticXMLParser::getParser();
    if(!$this->data = $parser->parse($data)) {
      $this->code = JOBAMATIC_XMLPARSER_ERROR;
      $this->error = 'JobamaticXMLParser error: ' . $parser->getErrorMessage();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That little `if` condition is basically saying: IF `$query` does **NOT** have the word `golf` in it, append (ADD) the word `golf` to the end of the `$query` string.

```
if( strpos( $query, 'golf' ) === false) { 
    $query .= 'golf';
}
```

Based on your question, surely you just need to change it to :

```
if(empty($query) || $query == "" || $query == NULL) {
    $query = "golf";
} else {
    $query = trim($query);
}
```

That's what you're chasing right? a check to see that if the query string is empty or null, add `golf` to it or just trim it?